# How can I resize image captured by default camera?

Tags: android

I capture photo with default camera by calling

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ApplicationData.CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Then I save the photo to sdcard and retrieve it and set it to ImageView

```
OutputStream output;
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
output = new FileOutputStream(file);
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
output.flush();
output.close();
mThumbnaiImagelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mImageThumbNail.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

What I want in ImageView is exactly the same like thumbnail image of the device.For example:

[image]

But it become like this

[image]

So my question is:

1/How can I resize captured image?

2/Is any other way I can set image to ImageView without bitmap? Because when I set ImageView with Bitmap, it look terrible, like this (the image's size is 512x512)

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); in your onActivityResult then it will return thumbnail image not actual image.

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to imageview.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }
```

then your onActivityResult() method should be like this.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Here is getBitmap() method used in onActivityResult().

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with in.close(); could create a null-pointer exception